# 17499 Firebase App Check token is invalid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an Android app project that is already live and that project is running on Firebase database and for login Firebase phone authentication. when I found a source code i ran the debug app into my phone but could not be login through the OTP because the OTP was not receiving. so I have added my SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys to Firebase and downloaded the new 'google-services.json' file and added it to the project. then again I tried to send OTP and I got OTP and I am successfully logged in.
But on the next day anyone not getting OTP on the live app and my debug app(which have new 'googel-services.json' file) also not able to getting OTP. I am not getting what is happening if that is because of JSON file changes then that should be working in my debug app but it is not working anywhere. getting an error is "SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Firebase App Check token is invalid.".
Firebase Databse is working fine.
Please help me to get out of this issue